# How to Change the id generator to serial like 1,2,3,etc?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
@staticmethod
def generatePackageID():
    f = open("package_id")
    id = f.readline()
    id = id.strip()
    idw = int(id)
    idw += 1
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(int(idw))
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
    return int(id)
```

Change this to generate serial number like 1,2,3,4,5,6,etc

Comment: This thing... does not work. It shouldn't work because you want to write in read-only file

Comment: Not sure to understand the question : it is already generating increasing number.

Comment: no it is generation a random long id